# How do I import a dump for a deleted tablespace?

Tags: oracle, dump, tablespaces

I'm trying to import a database dump, however I am encountering this error:

```
ORA-39083: Object type TABLE:"MYSCHEMA"."MINF" failed to create with error:
ORA-00959: tablespace '_$deleted$5$0' does not exist
Failing sql is:
CREATE TABLE "MYSCHEMA"."MINF" (
    "P_MID" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE
    , "XML_ORIG_MSG" "SYS"."XMLTYPE"
    , "XML_MSG" "SYS"."XMLTYPE"
    , "P_OFFICE" CHAR(3 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE
    , "P_DEPARTMENT" CHAR(3 BYTE) DEFAULT '...'
    , "P_MSG_TYPE" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE) DEFAULT '...'
    , "P_MSG_SUB_TYPE" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
    , "P_CDT_MOP" VARCHAR2(6 BYTE)
    , "P_PREFERRED_CDT_MOP" VARCHAR2(6
```

It's seems the tablespace for the MINF table has been dropped before getting the dump.

Is there a workaround to still import this table?

Update:

I have tried `impdp` statement, with the same result:

```
./impdp system/****** 
DIRECTORY=GPPDUMP 
DUMPFILE=SPOCBC_SCD02.ROCKY.20120919102739.dmp.1
,SPOCBC_SCD02.ROCKY.20120919102739.dmp.2
,SPOCBC_SCD02.ROCKY.20120919102739.dmp.3
,SPOCBC_SCD02.ROCKY.20120919102739.dmp.4 
LOGFILE=baru.log 
REMAP_SCHEMA=SPOCBC_SCD02:OCBCGPP5 
REMAP_TABLESPACE=_$deleted$5$0:P_DATA
```

Comment: Did you try `REMAP_TABLESPACE` (assuming this is impdp).

Comment: I used the sql developer to import the schema. There is a section to remap the tablespace ( dropdown ). Haven't try the impdp.

Comment: You'll need to put double quotes around the source tablespace name in your `impdp` command since the tablespace name appears to be case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that the default (and/or temporary) tablespace for MYSCHEMA was dropped. If that is the case, give MYSCHEMA a new tablespace, with quota and re-run.

This can be checked by viewing the entries in dba_users.

This is a bug and should normally not occur.